# Сортировка вставками на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, функции, сортировка

Хотел разобраться с сортировкой вставками на питоне. Сам я реализовал на питоне такой код:

```
def InsertionSort(A):
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        key = A[j]
        i = j - 1
        while A[i] > key and i >= 0:
            A[i + 1], A[i] = A[i], A[i + 1]
            i -= 1
    return A
```

, то есть просто через обмен переменных значениями. Но в интернете везде код примерно такой:

```
def InsertionSort(A):
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        key = A[j]
        i = j - 1
        while i >= 0 and A[i] > key:
            A[i + 1] = A[i]
            i -= 1
        A[i + 1] = key
    return A
```

Так вот назрел вопрос: можно ли первый код считать алгоритмом сортировки вставкой или же это немного другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, первый код - разновидность сортировки пузырьком (элемент ползёт на свое место, обмениваясь с каждым встречным).

В сортировке вставками выполняются "полуобмены" - т.е. элемент извлекается, бОльшие сдвигаются на одну позицию, элемент вставляется - один раз. При этом операций присвоения в среднем меньше получается.